# Is there a WordPress plugin that can post to Google+?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, google-plus

I am using WP to Twitter on my WordPress blog to trigger a tweet every time I post something. Obviously this is for Twitter only, I need something to post on Google+ too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615245/publish-wordpress-posts-in-google-plus - Google plus appears not to allow this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted above - not currently, but you may want to keep an eye on [Simple Google Connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-google-connect/). Otto has created other social connect plugins that are quite popular. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are no APIs from google+ as yet ... It's a big feature we are all waiting for

Comment: I don’t. The absence of automatic posts is what G+ makes better than other networks. :)

Answer (score 1):

According to  [this page](https://developers.google.com/+/api/), the Google+ API only allows read-only access, thus making it currently impossible to post directly on Google+.